# How to restart an iterator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

How to restart an iterator?

I have a list of columns names like this:

```
my_column_names = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "F", "G", "H"]
```

And I take a csv file with rows like this:

```
A,500
B,3.0
C,87
A,200
A,300
B,3.5
D,CALL
E,CLEAN
F,MADRID
G,28000
H,SPAIN
A,150
B,1.75
C,103
D,PUT
```

I want to make a csv file with this format:

```
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H
500,3.0,87,,,,,
200,,,,,,,
300,3.5,,CALL,CLEAN,MADRID,28000,SPAIN
150,1.75,103,PUT,,,,
```

My code:

```
iter_column_names = itertools.cycle(my_column_names)
my_new_line = []
for old_line in new_file:
    column_name = iter_column_names.__next__()
    if old_line[0] == column_name:
        my_new_line.append(old_line[1])
    else:
        my_new_line.append('')
    if column_name == "H":
        print(my_new_line)   # to change by writeline() when it works fine
        my_new_line = []
```

But it doesn't work like I need.  I suppose that the problem is that it needs to restart de `iter_column_names` every time that it reaches "H" element. Or not?

Comment: You can just recreate the `cycle()` iterator, instead of 'restarting'. Your approach is not that suitable, however.

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters. I've realized I'm wrong, but I don't found any solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a `csv.DictWriter()` and use a dictionary to handle the rows. That way you can detect if a column has been seen already, and start a new row:

```
import csv

fields = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H')

with open('inputfile.csv', newline='') as infh, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfh:
    reader = csv.reader(infh)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfh, fields)
    writer.writeheader()
    row = {}
    for key, value in reader:
        if key in row:
            # new row found, write old
            writer.writerow(row)
            row = {}
        row[key] = value
    # write last row
    if row:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import csv
>>> import sys
>>> infh = '''\
... A,500
... B,3.0
... C,87
... A,200
... A,300
... B,3.5
... D,CALL
... E,CLEAN
... F,MADRID
... G,28000
... H,SPAIN
... A,150
... B,1.75
... C,103
... D,PUT
... '''.splitlines()
>>> outfh = sys.stdout
>>> fields = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H')
>>> if True:
...     reader = csv.reader(infh)
...     writer = csv.DictWriter(outfh, fields)
...     writer.writeheader()
...     row = {}
...     for key, value in reader:
...         if key in row:
...             # new row found, write old
...             writer.writerow(row)
...             row = {}
...         row[key] = value
...     # write last row
...     if row:
...         writer.writerow(row)
... 
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H
500,3.0,87,,,,,
17
200,,,,,,,
12
300,3.5,,CALL,CLEAN,MADRID,28000,SPAIN
40
150,1.75,103,PUT,,,,
22
```

The numbers in between (`17`, `12`, `40`, `22`) are the `writer.writerow()` return values (bytes written).

Comment: @thefourtheye: indeed. The `csv` module wants to handle universal newline translation itself, so you need to switch that off at the file object.

Comment: @thefourtheye: yup, building a demo I discovered that too. :-)

Comment: `for key, value in reader:
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack`

Comment: @Trimax: then your input file has empty columns, it appears. Use `for row in reader:` then unpack with `try:`, `key, value = row`, `except ValueError:`, `continue`, to skip such rows.

Comment: It doesn't work.  The new code in the question.  The output csv file is populated only with the name field.

Comment: @Trimax: *doesn't work* is **not** a problem description. The code works *just fine* for the input data you've shown in your question. If the code doesn't work with your actual data, then there are crucial differences in your actual data. **Find out what those differences are**, and adjust the code. If you still have problems with that, perhaps asking a new question is the better option; comments really are not suited for extensive troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

First, you probably shouldn't use the `__next__()` method. `__xxx__` methods are rarely supposed to be used on their own (hence the double underscore awkwardness). The `next()` built-in method has the effect that you need. You could use the `csv` module, but sometimes a manual approach can be simpler:

```
for old_line in new_file:
    for column_name in my_column_names:
        if old_line[0] == column_name:
            my_new_line.append(old_line[1])
        else:
            my_new_line.append('')
        try:
            old_line = next(new_file)
        except StopIteration:
            break
    print ','.join(my_new_line)
    my_new_line = []
```

Note how the `next` is actually used on the (implicit) file line iterator, and instead we just loop over the column names.